# How to copy an animation from one bone to another bone?

Tags: rigging

Is it possible to copy animations from one bone to another?

I have one armature per leg in my robot rig.

Now i made a follow path bone constraint and animated the offset.

Can i copy that animation to the other bones?

[image]

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but [this YT video](https://youtu.be/imbIsNAvUpM) might give you a few ideas.

Comment: Thanks John, i already watched and rebuild that ;) i am working now on his successor video and he copied it manually and i hoped there would be a better way...

Comment: Ah ok. I did that one sometime last year.

Comment: that vid was also my inspiration to make my spider robot also with 6 legs :D https://youtu.be/PjK7SH9Y7Ik but it was a pain to animate the movement XD

Comment: For me personally: he makes the best Blender tutorials at the moment.